# Reinstalling Windows 8 with the existing product key

Tags: windows, windows-8

I recently purchased an ASUS laptop with Windows 8 installed. The hard disk capacity
is 750 GB. I checked the C drive and could see that they have used almost 40/50 GB for installing Windows 8, including all the graphics drivers and other drivers.

I would like to format my machine and reinstall Windows 8 from scratch. I don't want to use the recovery drive or any other means. Is it possible to install only Windows 8 with the existing product key?

The rest of the software or drivers for my computer will be installed manually.

Comment: Just use the "Reset" feature built into Windows 8. This will reset Windows 8 to a default state. If you want to keep your files ( standard desktop applications will be removed ) just use "Refresh" instead.  You are not going to save any space by installing from a installation media.

Answer (score 3):

Get a clean Windows 8 DVD (MSDN/Technet) or remove the ei.cfg from your current DVD. When you now install Windows 8, the setup will use the Key which is embedded to the UEFI.

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is that most people with a computer that came with Windows 8 do not have an installation media provided to them.  Between the recovery partition and the `Reset` and `Referesh` features in Windows 8 its not really required.  Most people sadly do not have access to MSDN/Technet because of the cost.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a phone-activation:

1. Press Windows key + X then click Run, then type:   slui.exe  4
2. Next press the 'ENTER' key
3. Select your 'Country' from the list.
4. Choose the 'Phone Activation' option.
5. Stay on the phone (do not select/press any options) and wait for a person to help you with activation.
6. Explain your problem clearly to the support person.

It should be noted that people seem to have better luck with the support number than the activation number in terms of ability to reissue keys. That number is: 800-936-5700 if you're in the United States.

[Reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-8-pro-upgrade-product-key-cant-be-used-to/1726d238-98fb-4634-a468-04645a8ee097)

Comment: This doesn't answer any questions of the original post

Comment: "Is it possible to install only Windows 8 with the existing product key?" was the question. Upon reinstallation, you will be prompted with activation options. This is where you'd apply this advice. Using an existing product key, as aforementioned, you could possibly get a new product key from Microsoft using this method.